# In windows, why does the hotkey for "properties" on the context menu vary?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

On the Windows OS, why is the hotkey for `Properties` on the right-click context menu for explorer sometimes `r` and sometimes `o`?

I have experienced the variation on the pro versions of Windows 7 & 10, and I can't explain what configures it to be one or the other.

Comment: I don't know if or why these hotkeys vary, but why don't you use ALT+Enter to open the properties dialog. That works for me since Windows 3.1

Comment: It depends what other items are on the menu ...

Comment: @DavidPostill I thought that might be the case, but I am asking for specifics. Thanks

Comment: Well if something else is using r then it will be o or the other way around ...

Comment: On Windows 7 for example there is o(pen) and r(estore previous versions). I also have other items beginning with o and r. There is also p(rint) and p(roperties). Confusing huh?

Comment: It has always been "r" even in Windows 7.. don't remember using "o" ever, in any version of Windows. You may enable "Enable shortcut underlines" in Accessibility Settings > keyboard to see which item has taken over "r".

Comment: @w32sh Nothing appears on the context menu which has the r hotkey, yet the properties hotkey is still o. I'm wondering if this is a home vs pro thing?

Comment: Ok. It may be caused by the language setting. Pl check this out: [keyboard shortcuts - Change Properties accelerator in windows 8 context menu - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/545344/change-properties-accelerator-in-windows-8-context-menu?rq=1)